# How to store Set of integers with duplicates

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to store a set of integers with duplicates allowed, for example `1, 5, 3, 3, 4, 6`.

If I use a `HashSet`, the duplicates are lost.
A `List` feels wrong as the items have no order implied. I need to be able to delete items from the middle quickly which rules out `ArrayList`. `LinkedList` still implies the items have some order which I don't like.

Is there another data structure I should use for this? Or should I tell `HashSet` to compare `Integer` based on reference equality?

I know I can work around this in a few ways but I'm more interested in the most 'correct' solution.

Comment: The *definition* of `Set` is that it doesn't store duplicates (and even using reference equality with `Integer` wouldn't work; `Integer` tends to intern small values). What are you wanting to accomplish?

Comment: @chrylis Say I want to represent a bucket of tokens where each token has a number on it. Some of the tokens might have the same number but there is no order to the tokens in the bucket. What data structure is best to represent the bucket?

Comment: You want a "bag" or "multiset", which is basically a special-purpose `Map<K,Integer>`. Guava, as suggested by Marcin, is a good choice.

Answer (score 5):

You might use [Guava's multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), if this dependency is not a problem. As a bonus, guava has many other useful general-purpose utilities.

Answer (score 3):

The `LinkedList` is the way to go. 
If you need it sorted, you can use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29);

Answer (score 0):

Use a multiset-style collection. It is missing for some reason in Java libraries, so you'll want to either implement `Collection` directly yourself or use Google Guava's MultiSet.

A list is fine, and overhead is not bad. If you don't care about ordering, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

`List` will work just fine, its the easiest solution for your problem without any major drawbacks and this is most of the times favorable to [some elegant but complex ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Other than that see this answer [Duplicate values in the Set collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112539/duplicate-values-in-the-set-collection)